# How do I discourage iOS from terminating app while doing a critical operation?

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

I have an application that communicates with custom hardware over BLE. In normal circumstances, I want my application to terminate quickly when a user presses the home button. However, when my application is in the middle of updating firmware on my custom hardware, I want to dissuade iOS from terminating the application. This firmware operation will take about five minutes from start to finish. I know there is no way to prevent iOS from terminating the app absolutely, but can I do anything to dissuade it from terminating my application while it is doing its firmware update operation?

Comment: Hm, I doubt this is possible. If a user wishes to terminate the app, it will be terminated. I seriously doubt Apple would allow you to disrupt their user experience so much and prevent them from terminating an app. The most you can likely do is send them a notification upon termination that informs them that they need to re-open the app and allow the alotted amount of time.

Comment: @MikeG I'm not trying to override a user forcefully terminating my app or critical OS conditions like low memory. I'm simply trying to dissuade iOS from killing my app while updating firmware in the more normal cases (i.e., where memory is fine but the user has pressed the home button and started browsing the web while waiting for this firmware update).

Comment: @Rob Thanks Rob, those two pieces of information were excellent (the 3 minute limit, and bluetooth-central mention). If you want to put those in an answer, I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need 3 minutes or less, you can use [beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithName:expirationHandler:) when doing the update, so that the app will request time to continue to run in the background in order to complete the task even if the user hits the home button. The problem is that it only gives you 3 minutes, not more than that.

Given that 3 minutes is apparently not enough for you to complete your upload, if you go down this road, I'd suggest combining this will some very serious looking message on the screen telling the user to not leave the app. You could also, when the app is about to enter background (`applicationDidEnterBackground`), schedule a local notification that will alert the user to return to the app or face serious consequences if they don't.

Even better, you might be able to declare the app as one that requires a proper background mode. For example, there are dedicated background modes `bluetooth-central` or `bluetooth-peripheral` that might be applicable. Then the three minute limitation doesn't apply. See [Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23) in the *App Programming Guide for iOS.*